# Add Coustome stopwords list in countvectorizer

Tags: python, stop-words, countvectorizer

I'm learning Python, and trying to use `CountVectorizer` to remove some words. 
What I want is to replace `count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')` and read stopwords from a file.

Here is my code:

```
# Load the library with the CountVectorizer method
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
%matplotlib inline

# Helper function
def plot_10_most_common_words(count_data, count_vectorizer):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    words = count_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    total_counts = np.zeros(len(words))
    for t in count_data:
        total_counts+=t.toarray()[0]

    count_dict = (zip(words, total_counts))
    count_dict = sorted(count_dict, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[0:10]
    words = [w[0] for w in count_dict]
    counts = [w[1] for w in count_dict]
    x_pos = np.arange(len(words)) 

    plt.figure(2, figsize=(15, 15/1.6180))
    plt.subplot(title='10 most common words')
    sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1.25, rc={"lines.linewidth": 2.5})
    sns.barplot(x_pos, counts, palette='husl')
    plt.xticks(x_pos, words, rotation=90) 
    plt.xlabel('words')
    plt.ylabel('counts')
    plt.show()

# Initialise the count vectorizer with the English stop words
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

# Fit and transform the processed titles
count_data = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(papers['Abstract'])

# Visualise the 10 most common words
plot_10_most_common_words(count_data, count_vectorizer)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What was stopping you from doing it?

Answer (score 0):

First, read stop words from a file, making a list of them by using the `.split()` method:

```
with open("name_of_your_stop_words_file") as stop_words:
    your_stop_words_list = stop_words.read().split()
```

Then use this list instead of the string `'english'`:

```
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=your_stop_words_list)
```

(This assumes that your stop words file contains stop words delimited by whitespace characters only (e.g. spaces or tabs) if there are more than 1 of them in a line.)